# Applescript change folder and terminal commands

Tags: applescript

I have tried the following but cannot seem to get this to work:

```
do script "cd ~/desktop/test; for x in ls -1 | sed -e 's/^\(.\).*/\1/' | sort -u; do mv -i ${x}?* $x done"
```

I'm wanting to perform this command in applescript. I run this in applescript and I get an error regarding "" marks but am not sure how to correct it. I'm a complete newbie to applescript. willing to learn just a little lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

General when using the [do shell script](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command, you will need to use the [quoted form](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_613) property of text objects. In other words, do something like this.

```
set command to "ls"
set result to do shell script quoted form of command
display dialog result
```